# List reading empty when inside doInBackground of AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I am trying to read a list of integers inside of the `doInBackground` of `AsyncTask`. When I pass the list into the constructor of `AsyncTask`, it is full. But, by the time I get to the `doInBackground` function, it is empty. Any ideas?

```
public class floatingActionButtonClickListener implements View.OnClickListener{

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(mAdapter.getDeleteModeStatus()){
            // Delete items from database
            ArrayList<Integer> IDsToDelete = mAdapter.getJournalIDsToDelete();
            new DeleteDatabase().execute(IDsToDelete);

            // Turn FAB back to regular button
            mFAB.setImageResource(R.drawable.baseline_add_white_48); // Turn FAB to delete button

            // Disable delete mode
            mAdapter.exitDeleteMode();

            // Load database
            new LoadDatabase().execute();
        }
        else{
            Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), AcitivtyJournal.class);
            int journalType = Constants.JOURNALTYPE_FULL;
            intent.putExtra(Constants.JOURNAL_TYPE, journalType);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
}

private class DeleteDatabase extends AsyncTask <ArrayList<Integer>, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        mProgressBarHolder.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(ArrayList<Integer>... arrayLists) {
        ArrayList<Integer> IDsToDelete = arrayLists[0];

        AppDatabase db = Room.databaseBuilder(getApplicationContext(), AppDatabase.class, "JournalEntries")
                .build();

        for(Integer idToDelete : IDsToDelete){
            db.mJournalEntriesDao().deleteCompleteJournalEntry(idToDelete);
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        mProgressBarHolder.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Where you call `DeleteDatabase` ?

Comment: How do you know that `mAdapter.getJournalIDsToDelete()` returned a full list? Do you log the size of it anywhere?

Comment: @cricket_007 I know because of the debugger. `IDsToDelete` before `DeleteDatabase()` is called and during its callbacks

Comment: @JohnJoe `DeleteDatabase` is called in an `onClickListener()` for a `FloatingActionButton` I added the code above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Posting for people in the future who may have similar questions.

Embarrasingly enough, the `ArrayList<Integer>` was coming empty because I was deleting it in the function `mAdapter.exitDeleteMode();` after I call `AsyncTask().execute()`.

I was not aware that when I send the list to the `AsyncTask` it was the exact address of the list and not just a new list (that is, until I posted the comment above, and then it clicked). I think I got that train of thinking from C++ or another language. I don't remember which.

**Solution:** The solution I came up with is to just move `mAdapter.exitDeleteMode()` into of `onPostExecute()`instead of having it in the `onClick()` method.

**Another Potential Solution:** I believe another solution that would work (but I did not test) would be to just insert a `new ArrayList<Integer> ()` into the `AsyncTask`

Answer (score 1):

This is not how you use and AsyncTask. You need to declare the parameters and then recieve them in the callback.

Please also note that you are trying to access the same data(IDsToDelete) from two threads(Main and Background), in your way, without proper syncronization.

```
private class DeleteDatabase extends AsyncTask<ArrayList<Integer>, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(ArrayList<Integer>... arrayLists) {
        ArrayList<Integer> params = arrayLists[0];
        // Do what you need
    }
}

ArrayList<Integer> IDsToDelete = mAdapter.getJournalIDsToDelete();
new DeleteDatabase().execute(IDsToDelete);
```

When you have multithreading you need to look for two things:

- atomic execution of operations
- memory visibility.

  There is a shared memory and every CPU caches the data. When you create something from one thread you can't just expect that the second thread will just read it. In your case you are creating the AsyncTask and inject the params from one thread, but then you read them in doInBackground from another. In general when you go through a synchronized block or hit a volatile variable(I say in general, because I also don't fully understand how JVM works), the thread flushes it's cache to the main memory and then reads also from it. This is how the data is shared. That is why it is better to use the framework way, because the frame will take care of proper publication of your data between threads. You are ok with immutable data, but a List is not such thing. And even if you declare the reference as immutable, you might see the right object from both threads, but the data they are holding might be old.

Just to be clear. I am not saying that the previous way was not working. I am saying that it is on good will. You can't just share data betweeb threads and hope it works.

Comment: Thank Yavor, I just did it like that; however, I'm still having the same issue. https://imgur.com/a/f9GjFiJ It's strange because in these pictures you can see that both arrayLists and grabbing information from the same address, the one in AsyncTask is just empy. Btw, in what way is the way I'm trying to do not synchronized? I assumed it was because I'm calling `mAdapter.getJournalIDstoDelete();` before I call `DeleteDatabase();`. With that, `IDsToDelete` will be filled before `DeleteDatabase()` is called

Comment: There was not enough space to reply to you as a comment. About why you don't see the data... I am as surprised as you are.. .